# Is there an equivalent statement in MySQL that corresponds to FETCH ABSOLUTE in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, cursor, database-migration

I'm converting a stored procedure from SQL Server to MySQL 8.
But I have no idea how to handle FETCH ABSOLUTE.
Can anyone suggest me how to convert this into MySQL 8?

Comment: You would be better off posting your entire T-SQL query, and your MySQL attempt, so that the volunteers can help you more easily.

Comment: That isn't relevant to the question here though, Dmitry.

Comment: Why isn't it relevant, @Larnu?

Comment: Because PDO is a connection mananger for accessing a database; the underlying query you use will be the same regardless of if you're using OLEDB, ODBC, PDO, etc (parameter implementation differs, but the query format itself isn't).

Comment: Do you want the new code to be a MySQL Stored Proceedure, or can it be an inline query in PHP

Comment: I'm using the cursor in the stored procedure, so it's not a problem of whether to use PDO or not.

Comment: I can see [MySql 8.0 Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fetch.html)  we don't have much flavours of Fetch statement as exist in SQL Server

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @RiggsFolly. It cannot be used as an inline query in PHP,

Comment: You are right, @ShakeerMirza. That's why I posted a question here.

Comment: We cannot really tell you how to rewrite your code without seeing your code (and probably an explanation what it is supposed to do). Your code is using that absolute fetch to achieve some goal. There are usually many ways to achieve a specific result, and you are asking us to tell you those ways, without telling us about that result. Which of those would be useful here depends on your code. Generic solutions will usually not perform well. (An example: replace the absolute fetch with a reexecution of your cursor followed by a while loop that does n fetches.).

Comment: @DmitryShylgenko just explain the logic what `FETCH ABSOLUTE` does in your code, so that equal MySQL code will shared but important **Need more info**